# ImportError: cannot import name 'Darknet' from 'darknet'

Tags: python, import, darknet

I am trying to use the `darknet` package in my Python project, but I am getting the following error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'Darknet' from 'darknet'`

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the package, but the issue persists. Here is the relevant code:

```
from darknet import Darknet
model = Darknet("cfg/yolov3.cfg")
```

I am using Python version 3.9 and 'darknet' version 0.2. I am running on Windows 11.

Comment: Is your python script itself named `darknet.py`?

Answer (score 0):

You fail to mention which repo you are using.  There are several hundreds when it comes to Darknet.  The one you probably should be using (I'm writing this in March 2024) is this one:  https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet#table-of-contents

Note the src-python subdirectory with the python Darknet module and example source code.